# show getPriceHtml() in custom module through ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

I'm trying insert price block in my module. 
My Controller.php

```
public function indexAction() {
    $sku = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
    if (!$sku) { return false; }
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    if (!$product) { return false; }
    $response = [
        $product->getPrice(),
        $product->getName(),
        $product->getThumbnail(),
        $product->getIsSalable(),
        $product->getProductUrl(),
    ];

    $productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
    $data = $productBlock->getPriceHtml($product, true);

    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($response, $data));
}
```

And my Ajax section in template.phtml:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: params,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response, data) {
                if (response) {
                    var array = response;                    
                    var name = array[1];
                    var image = array[2];
                    var stock1 = array[3];
                    var url = array[4];

                    $j(idPrice).html(data);
                    $j(idName).text(name);
                    $j(idName).attr('href', url);
                    $j(idName).attr('title', name);
                    $j(idStock).text(stock);
                    $j(idImage).attr('src', "/media/catalog/product/" + image);
                }
            }
        });
```

But this leads to an error Ajax request.

Comment: What's the error you're getting ?

Comment: By mistake, I mean the wrong work. In this case, the blank page. Although if I remove the code relating to the price block everything works fine.

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, there must be an error somewhere. Try accessing your controller route directly via URL instead of AJAX and see what it gives you.

Comment: I tried "site.com/ajaxproductinfo?sku=PR-24DC-TN" but again it gives me just a blank page :(

Comment: Check your webserver error log and check the source code of the page

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved.

```
public function indexAction() {
    $sku = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
    if (!$sku) { return false; }
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    if (!$product) { return false; }
    $productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
    $response = [
        $product->getPrice(),
        $product->getName(),
        $product->getThumbnail(),
        $product->getIsSalable(),
        $product->getProductUrl(),
        $product = $productBlock->getPriceHtml($product, true),
    ];

    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($response));
}
```